# WPF Code Behind - Pause / Resume All storyboards for dynamic content

Tags: wpf

I have dynamic content loaded into a control. I wish to build a collection of all Storyboards present (if any) within the content and pause/resume them depending on the situation.

So far I have been able to build a complete list of UI Elements that were loaded into the control, but from there how would I deduce if storyboards have been attached to any of them?